# Identify non matching record in the row - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have below data. I want to remove odd out of that, which is at position 62. Because all other are set (Where). Basically combination of open bracket, where string and closing bracket.

```
id  pos    pattern
--------------------
5   26     (
1   48     where
8   60     )
2   62     where
6   74     (
3   109    where
9   121    )
7   133    (
4   168    where
10  180    )
```

Please suggest.

Comment: In what order, by `pos`?

Comment: In my case, it can be only one independent Where can exist, so yes it can be on pos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used sub-queries to select the TOP 1 before (ordered by pos desc) and TOP 1 after  (ordered by pos asc) then checked they if they were not the correct values

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable t
WHERE t.pattern='where'
AND(
    ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 tPrevious.pattern FROM MyTable tPrevious WHERE tPrevious.pos<t.pos ORDER BY tPrevious.pos DESC),'') !='('
    OR ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 tNext.pattern FROM MyTable tNext WHERE tNext.pos>t.pos ORDER BY tNext.pos),'') !=')'
)
```

Comment: That is very good thinking. It works. But it fails when it doesnt open and close brackets in the table. Like,
id  pos    pattern
--------------------
1   48     where

Comment: Adding ISNULL around the subqueries may fix that. Will tweak my code when at my PC

Comment: I have added ISNULL checks

Comment: It worked fine for so many queries. But failed for one scenario.
id pos pattern
------------------
1 133 where
3 148 (
6 153 )
4 167 (
2 212 where
5 228 (
7 250 )
8 281 )

To be precise, I collected that data from query like, Select * from t1 Where id In (1, 2) and exists (Select id from t2 where name in ('1', '2'))

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LEAD/LAG` to get the previous and next rows.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        prev = LAG(t.pattern) OVER (ORDER BY pos),
        nxt = LEAD(t.pattern) OVER (ORDER BY pos)
    FROM MyTable t
) t
WHERE t.pattern <> 'where' OR prev = '(' AND nxt = ')';
```

You can even delete via that derived table

```sql
DELETE t
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        prev = LAG(t.pattern) OVER (ORDER BY pos),
        nxt = LEAD(t.pattern) OVER (ORDER BY pos)
    FROM MyTable t
) t
WHERE t.pattern = 'where' AND (prev <> '(' OR nxt <> ')');
```

Comment: Its a good concept. I read it. thanks. But the query is not getting me the expected result.

Comment: Sorry got the logic slightly wrong have fixed